# GSA - Determining which queries need higher Click Rank from ASR

Tags: ranking, google-search-appliance

I have been analyzing click data from our Google Search Appliance (GSA) Advanced Search Reports (ASR), and I have run into a bit of an issue.  I am trying to generate a .csv report that is ordered by a "priority" that determines which queries would benefit from a **manual boost in Click Rank**.  An example entry in the report looks like this:

```
|   Query   | Avg Start Page | Avg Click Rank | Total Clicks | Unique Users | Attention Indicator |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| transfers |              0 |            5.5 |             9|             4|                88.72|
```

My current Indicator is following this formula:

```
Priority = ((Unique Users^2)*Avg Click Rank)+(Unique Users/Avg Click Rank)
```

In my formula, I am trying to lower the priority of cases where 1 user has many clicks (ex. a user clicks every link on a page, skewing results with higher clicks and click rank), and also lower priority of cases where only 1-2 users are searching for a query.

Is there a better way to analyze GSA click data based on a similar Priority metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no manual boost in click rank (other than faking the clicks).  You do have source biasing and also metadata biasing which could feed into that.

Click data should be used to judge the general performance of the system.  We generally aren't circling back to circumvent the self learning scorer.